Understanding Translation Disparity: 水が流れる
This felt like a Reddit question, but I found some merit to the discussion. So I am currently studying Japanese through One Shot, an RPG Maker game where you interact with the environment, and here I am interacting with a tub, with the dialogue saying "浴槽には水が流れない":

So Weblio has an entry that says 水が流れる means "to drain into," but I think the more general "water flows" works here; I currently have it translated as

The water will not flow into the tub.

Which...sounds weird. I checked with the English version and this was the translation:

So I am trying to understand the nuances of the Japanese translation based on the English. I know the に relates to how the water flows into something, since で would mark an action at a location---not used here. So what is the translation of 水が流れる here: is it just simply "the water will not drain into the tub"? The act of the water going into the tub is implied in the Japanese, but not the English.
I may be overthinking this, but I am not sure what the Japanese is exactly implying, as it seems to have a nuance not captured in the English. How should I break down the Japanese?

"The act of the water going into the tub is implied in the Japanese, but not the English." How do you interpret the verb "run" with regard to bathtubs?

In English "Run a bath" means "Fill the bath with water". Also, you would never say "drain into". Draining would always be about water leaving the bath.

So "water will not flow into the tub" is the translation and implies "The tub will not run"; however in no case is this saying the tub is not working, correct? In English I would likely say "the bath is not working," so maybe I am anchoring on the wrong thing.

It's true that if you can't run water in a tub, it's not working, but that's just the fact that "run" has multiple meanings in English. It doesn't mean there's a mismatch with the Japanese.

Your grammatical analysis seems perfect, and "Water will not flow into the tub" is a correct literal translation. に simply means "into" here.

浴槽に水が流れない
Water won't run into the tub (water supply issue)
浴槽から水が流れない
Water won't drain from the tub (drainage issue）
浴槽で水が流れない (unnatural)

I don't know the most natural way of saying these in English, but isn't "the tub won't run" a valid way to refer to the first situation? (Of course 走る doesn't work in Japanese.)

I was overthinking I guess. I think I understood に, but it was から that clarifies the meaning of 水が流れる; the definition has both drain and flow, and I struggled to understand what situation warranted which one.
